# "Class header expected instead" error

Tags: java, eclipse

Why do I get this error?

I've been trying to solve it.

```
package Controller;

import View.ViewGegevens; //Error
import Model.Persoon;
{
private String Voornaam;
private String Tussenvoegsels;
private String Achternaam;
private String Woonplaats;
private int Telefoonnummer;
private String Aardappel;}
public class InvullenData implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
```

Comment: By the way ... `private String Aardappel` ?
Wondering what kind of application this is now.

Comment: uhm, it was an class subject i got in did it there just for fun, sorry haha. solved it to btw ^^

Answer (score 2):

These lines should be within any of class or interface

```
{
private String Voornaam;
private String Tussenvoegsels;
private String Achternaam;
private String Woonplaats;
private int Telefoonnummer;
private String Aardappel;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

whatever the variables your declaring **must be enclosed within a class** because class is a type of **Wrapper Mechanism** unless they are declared inside the class those will not be available to your class